# How to configure dev proxy server with vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to communicate with my node js server. My vue.config.js is the following:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3080',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

My UI is hosted on port 5173. When I try making an API call with axios, I see the following request "http://127.0.0.1:5173/api/login" in the network tab. Does anyone what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the problem with this? Requests are supposed to be done to 5173. This is a config for Node proxy, it doesn't affect code that's evaluated in browser

Comment: What if I want my requests to go to port 3080?

Comment: Then you should do them to 3080 in axios urls

Comment: So much for the proxy then…

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's to avoid problems with CORS and requests urls in local environment. If you don't have them then you probably don't need a proxy

Comment: Figured out the issue. I had to write the config above in vite.config.ts instead of vue.config.js. Thanks